# Is it ok to use $_SESSION['variables'] in Drupal 8?

Tags: session, drupal-8

I need a way to store temporary data for anonymous users.

Apparently this is not possible with:

```
\Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')
```

Unless you write a custom constructor for the session management and stuff, which seems a little far-fetched to me?

I tried using

```
\Drupal::service('user.shared_tempstore')
```

But that saves the temp data for all anonymous users. So it's not linked to a single user.

Using raw $_SESSION['data'] works fine, but I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be doing this in Drupal and how safe/unsafe it is to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've been using plain PHP $_SESSION variables for a while now.
Did some research on them and they should be perfectly safe to use.
They're working correctly everywhere I use them and they have been working correctly for a while.

Don't think there's any issue using them in Drupal 8.

Answer (score 4):

I am not answering your specific question (regarding `$_SESSION`) because I have successfully used:

```php
$session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('your_module');
$session->set('whatever', $whatever);
```

from within procedural code (i.e. hooks, themes) without problems.

Pay attention that this private tempstore has to be assigned to a module (for the lack of a better way of saying this) which is the purpose of this line

```php
$session = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('your_module')
```

After you get the private tempostore you can now set and get the session values:

```php
$session->get('whatever');
$session->set('whatever', $whatever);
```

EDIT

Sorry, you explained correctly. I didn't get the critical part 100% ;)

You can always access the Session object from the request.

```php
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
$session->set('whatever', 'hello');
$value = $session->get('whatever', 'default');
```

Comment: Doesn't work for anonymous users, should've probably made that more obvious in my initial question.

Comment: @PascalClaes You explained correctly. I didn't get the critical part :) I have edited the answer.

Comment: Would this create a unique session for each unique anonymous visitor?

Comment: @PascalClaes Unless you have a specific use case or some specific caching thing, yes it should be unique to each anonymous user. By getting the session directly from the request you are using the "native session object" (for the lack of a better term).

Comment: The services user.private_tempstore and user.shared_tempstore are deprecated in favour of tempstore.private and tempstore.shared.

https://www.drupal.org/node/2935639

Answer (score 4):

Sessions (Drupal 8) are used via the simple Session implementation of SessionInterface interface. [See Complete Tutorial of Sessions (Drupal 8).](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Example:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('name', 'Yash');
$session->get('name');

// set flash messages
$session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');

// retrieve messages
foreach ($session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array()) as $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-notice">'.$message.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Should test this before accepting the answer, but looks very useful!

Comment: Yeah looks good, however needs more testing. Generates errors such as this;

RuntimeException: Failed to start the session: already started by PHP. in Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\NativeSessionStorage->start() (line 131 of  /vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage.php).